Change in concentration of a reaction effects
I came across this question:
An increase in the concentration of the reactants of a reaction leads to the change in-

heat of reaction
threshold energy
collision frequency
activation energy

I am confused between 1 and 3.
The answer is given as 3 everywhere but what I don't understand is that heat of reaction (by which I think they mean enthalpy) increases with increases in concentration of reactants so why can't it be the answer?

Usually heat of reaction refers to the enthalpy per mole not on the actual concentration.

IMHO, the expression heat of reaction ( compared to reaction enthalpy) may sound more ambiguous, so learning students may doubt if it is in kJ or kJ/mol. (It is the latter)

i agree with you It can be hard to give the politically correct answer to a flawed question. Ask anyone who has experienced an explosion or eruption from using inappropriate concentrations or amounts; increasing a reaction rate can have consequences.

@jimchmst It can be even harder for a student to ask about a possibly weird question, that may be flawed but you are not sure about it. Especially in culture with high respect to teaching authorities and textbooks. (It must be me who is wrong...) // Such a student may receive a wide range of responses. :-)

I believe the questions wants an answer that is the most obvious effect of increasing the concentration of the reactants. Which in this case happens to be the "collision frequency", as with an increase in the concentration, more collisions between the molecules will occur. Furthermore the Heat of reaction can also be understood as the amount of heat that must be added or removed during a chemical reaction in order to maintain constant pressure and temperature(along side its defination of enthalphy, ofcourse). This is also affected by the concentration of the reactants(to an extent), however, is clearly not favourable when being compared to the option of "collision frequency", as it can more directly be understood/predicted.
Regardless I do agree that an option with both "collision frequency" and "heat of the reaction" should have been there.
